# iOS: Rename NSString for a loop

Tags: ios, nsstring, rename

```
NSString *string = @"Test";
```

Is it possible to rename this string? I'd like to make it dynamic with an int at the end:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 19; i++)
{
   // here the name of the string should be dynamic, so that I'll get 20 NSString (titled like string_00 to string_20)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to introduce new *local variables* in Objective C. When you need multiple data objects accessed with an integer index, use arrays or `NSArray` objects:

```
NSString *strings[20];
for (int i = 0; i <= 19; i++) {
    strings[i] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Test%d", i];
}
```

or

```
NSMutableArray *strings = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i = 0; i <= 19; i++) {
    [strings addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Test%d", i]];
}
```

Comment: Add them to a NSMutableArray.

Comment: @Cyrille: Yes, right. But when I use `[array setValue:@"" forKey:@""];` it does not seem to work..

Comment: I guess he needs a way to check if a string exists append an integer with it, until it becomes a unique value till 20

Comment: @filou Because `setValue:forKey:` is not what you use on an array (it's for key-value programming). Use `[array replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:@"Test123"]`.

Comment: @filou NSMutableArray doesn't have a `setValue:forKey:` method. I think you're wanting a [`NSMutableDictionary`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight the first code is exactly what I was looking for :) thank you very much!